# Randomize between two pictures

Tags: java, random

I’m building a program and I’m stuck at picking a random image that already is defined in the program.

Here’s the code:

```
Image Opic = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Resource/O1.png"));
Image Xpic = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Resource/X1.png"));
Image PlayerPic = new Random[Opic,Xpic];
Image AiPic = new Random[Opic,Xpic];
```

Comment: What language is this in? Doesn't look like any JavaScript I've ever written.

Comment: Well welcome to SO anyway. Have a look at this please to get a better understanding of how to properly ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: i think it's in java because i using java fx application in netbeans

is my question not properly written ?? sorry then i'm tryng my best for it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Image Opic = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Resource/O1.png"));
Image Xpic = new Image(getClass().getResourceAsStream("Resource/X1.png"));

Image PlayerPic = Math.random() > 0.5 ? Opic : Xpic;
```

Not sure what language you are actually coding in, since it does not look like javascript (well not Java either) to me. But this is just a demonstration in Java on how this problem can be approach. You can almost for sure be able to find similar method in any language.

Comment: it's working fine now thank you very much for the help